# ADODB и экранирование имен

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ado

По своей глупости одно из полей в таблице назвал 'show' - зарезервированное слово. Поэтому вот такая конструкция:

```
$res = $DB->AutoExecute('debtor', $data, 'UPDATE', "id_debtor = '".$id_debtor."'");
```

ругается:

> 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SHOW=1 WHERE id_debtor ...

на то, что слово show не экранировано. Надо вот так: `show`. Как ADODB заставить экранировать название таблиц и полей?

Comment: А апострофы не помогают? Например "'SHOW'=". Кстати и строчку с prepare не мешало бы привести.